# Unable to delete a row from website with php

Tags: php

Hi im making Crud app with php mysqli procedural language.i was able to retrieve and insert data but unable to delete. when i clicked on delete link it goes to delete.php page but nothing happens.
db.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','123','app');

?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CRUD</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="table table-bordered ">
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Fisrtname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
  </tr>
    <?php
include 'db.php';
$query ="select *from people";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
<td><a href='delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Delete</a></td>
<td><a href='edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Edit</a></td>

</tr>
<?php
}
?>
    <div class="container">
            <a href="add_records.php" class="btn btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp; Add Records</a>


        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

delete.php

```
<?php

include 'db.php';
if (isset($_GET('id'))) {
    $delete_id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "delete from people where id = '$delete_id'";
    $run = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if ($run) {
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection: use parameter binding...

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Second of all, your code is open to SQL injection. You should look into that, because it'd be incredibly easy for any user to access your database. Finally, can you `var_dump()` for `$_GET('id')` and show the structure of the table?

Comment: "Nothing happens" is a misleading description.  *Something* must be happening.  Have you turned on error reporting?  Checked error logs?  Note that your logic in `delete.php` *explicitly does nothing* if the GET value isn't present or if the query fails.  So... Is the GET value present?  Is the query failing?  What does `mysqli_error` tell you?

Comment: i am new to coding. i do not know how to var_dump

Comment: If you are new to php, always have php.net open in a browser window and input functions as you see people mention them. Do not simply say you do not know how to `function_name` without first looking it up.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in delete.php on line 4.

In `GET` array you have to use `[]` brackets around key name instead of `()`

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {...}
```

Comment: Please add a comment to "-" vote, if you dont agree with this answer.

Comment: i did change it to [ ] but still nothing happens,when i click on delete it takes me to delete.php page with blank white screen and row not gets deleted

Comment: Try to add `mysqli_error()`. If nothing, try to add `else` branch to know if the `isset` condition is `true`... Try to add some `echo`es before and after SQL query to see where is the program ended. Basic debugging.